# React Native - ignores styles

Tags: react-native

I have simple component

```jsx
class Cart extends Component {
    render() {

            return (
                <View style={{ flex: 1  }}>
                    <View slyle={{ backgroundColor: 'blue', width: 200, height: 200}}>

                            <Text>12</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            );

    }
}
```

And I get

[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error in line with:

```
 <View slyle={{ backgroundColor: 'blue', width: 200, height: 200}}>
```

should be **style** and NOT **slyle**

```
<View style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue', width: 200, height: 200}}>
```